# Scala types: reflect: How to find least upper bound of two types at runtime

Tags: scala, reflection, types

I'm implementing some expressions using Scala type system. To determine the type of `if-then-else` expression I need to be able to implement the following function

```
def leastUpperBound(thenPartType: Type, elsePartType: Type): Type
```

Is there a function somewhere in `scala.reflect._` to perform the evaluation? Or do I have to implement the search with those `*TypeApi` extractors?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the `universe` has a method `lub` just for that:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._

def leastUpperBound(thenPartType: Type, elsePartType: Type): Type =
  lub(List(thenPartType, elsePartType))
```

Using it:

```
trait Base
class A extends Base
class B extends Base

scala> com.Main.leastUpperBound(typeOf[A], typeOf[B])
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Base

scala> com.Main.leastUpperBound(typeOf[A], typeOf[String])
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = java.lang.Object

scala> com.Main.leastUpperBound(typeOf[A], typeOf[Int])
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Any
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew it should have been there.